# What is faster, Union or std::variant<>?

Tags: c++, c++17

I know that std::variant is easier to use and usually more convenient but which of those is actually faster?

Comment: Don't worry about speed before you profile the code.  Use the thing that is easier and more maintainable.  Once you have the code running then decide if you need to more performant, less maintainable code.

Comment: Definitionally `std::variant` can't be faster; it's a type-safe union wrapper, which means the types must be verified. When verification can be performed at compile time, it might be just as fast, but if runtime checks are performed, it will necessarily be slower. That said, @NathanOliver is right: Most of the time, this does not matter (I can't think of any programs where unions of any sort are used so much that they'd constitute the critical code path, performance-wise), so just use `std::variant` until you have evidence it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `union`s are probably faster than `std::variant`

There's a couple really easy ways to see how this could be. For starters, `std::variant` is, by design, slightly larger than a `union` featuring the exact same elements. So any operations that involve copying data, moving data around, etc., are never going to be faster than `union` outside of very esoteric use conditions.

On top of that, `std::variant` is type-checked, whereas `union` is not. So identical code to operate on the element contained in a `union` is going to be faster than on `std::variant`.

**That having been said**, it's possible to screw things up as a programmer. For example, the ideomatic way to do type-checking with `union`s is to do something like this:

```
struct my_union {
    union {
        int i;
        double a;
        std::string s;
    };
    size_t index;
    //...
};

int main() {
    my_union u;
    u.i = 15;
    u.index = 0;


    if(u.index == 0) {
        std::cout << u.i;
    } else if(u.index == 1) {
        std::cout << u.a;
    } else if(u.index == 2) {
        std::cout << u.s;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which, at least in terms of size and layout, is not that different to how `std::variant` is implemented, and may-or-may-not be slower or faster than the `std::visit` pattern with `std::variant`, depending on how clever the compiler is.

But as a programmer, your use case might be different, or your constraints might be different, or maybe the code was supposed to be different but later got edited to a different form. Whatever the case, the code used to manually perform type-checking on the `union` (assuming the programmer even remembers to do that, and doesn't screw up by ignoring it!) may not be so elegant or correct.

So yes, for a lot of reasons, `union` is probably faster than `std::variant`. But if you're trying to write safe, maintainable, code, you should prefer `std::variant`.

Comment: Benchmarks would be nice rather than just assumptions.

Comment: Faster what: initialising, copying, moving, destroying, extracting the value?